# pgstatindex - [42P01] ERROR: relation "idx_b527c53b636333c0a9f8e0edc4" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to analyze the indexes on one of my postgres tables:

```
SELECT * FROM pgstatindex('IDX_b527c53b636333c0a9f8e0edc4');
```

Output:

```
[42P01] ERROR: relation "idx_b527c53b636333c0a9f8e0edc4" does not exist
```

Why?

---

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple;

select
    t.relname as table_name,
    i.relname as index_name,
    a.attname as column_name
from
    pg_class t,
    pg_class i,
    pg_index ix,
    pg_attribute a
where
    t.oid = ix.indrelid
    and i.oid = ix.indexrelid
    and a.attrelid = t.oid
    and a.attnum = ANY(ix.indkey)
    and t.relkind = 'r'
    and t.relname = 'molly_offers'
order by
    t.relname,
    i.relname;
```

output:

| table_name | index_name | column_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| molly_offers | IDX_3b56ed8a380f6aec17ee596159 | sentByMollyUTC |
| molly_offers | IDX_572b528a0285c6c2b4d87135de | eventId |
| molly_offers | IDX_b527c53b636333c0a9f8e0edc4 | connectionGroupUTC |
| molly_offers | IDX_c37462b7c7239dff70b9baeac3 | punteamInstanceId |
| molly_offers | IDX_f03b78a43b1019152f22f28e1f | bms |
| molly_offers | PK_6b50c1bece64e09f498aeff4e66 | id |
| molly_offers | bms_asc_id_desc_idx | bms |
| molly_offers | bms_asc_id_desc_idx | id |
| molly_offers | mo_connectionGroupUTC_hash_idx | connectionGroupUTC |

Comment: Thanks! You can provide it as an answer :)

Comment: Another good example why using mixed-case identifiers result in more trouble than they are worth it.  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double quote the index name so that it does not get folded to lower case (see the error message):

```
SELECT * FROM pgstatindex('"IDX_b527c53b636333c0a9f8e0edc4"');
```